# hide post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How i hide post with a specific category in wordpress.
I frequently publish posts that I need to be hidden. They need to be published, so that someone who has their url can go to them, but I don't want them showing up on my homepage, in my recent posts widget, on my blog page, in my categories etc. I know I can normally use the WP Hide Post plugin for this, but somehow that isn't working for my site. When I create a new post and choose all the hide options WP Hide Post offers, the post still shows up on my blog page (which isn't my homepage).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your posts password protected in wordpress, which means that only the people you want, knows the password and can see the post. If you password protect your post, they will not appear on the front page, only viewable by link and then password input from user.